# Using a single user for mysql queries or multiple users for specific tasks?

Tags: mysql

Should I have multiple mysql user accounts with specific tasks (update,insert,select) for 1 web application OR a single mysql user account with multiple privileges?

Are there any specific pros and cons?

Comment: generally there'd be a single service account, with the security added at the application layer.

Comment: @pala_ so a single db user account with multiple privileges is the normal standard?

Comment: That's been the case on everything i've worked on, yeah.